# C# Selecting text in form1 from form2

Tags: c#

Okay, so I have my main form (`Form1`) and `SearchReplace` form. My `SearchReplace` form contains a textbox and a button. When the button is pressed, it is supposed to select whatever was in the textbox in `Form1`, but just does nothing. Can anyone help me? Not throwing me an error, just not doing anything runtime.

**SearchReplace**

```
    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1.searchT = textBox1.Text;


        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        form1.searchText();
        this.Close();
    }
```

**Form1 searchText**

```
    public void searchText() // search function
    {

        if (searchT != null)
        {
            if (textBox1.TextLength > 0)
            {
                if (textBox1.Text.Contains(searchT))
                {
                    textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.IndexOf(searchT);
                    textBox1.SelectionLength = searchT.Length;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

searchT is a public string created in `Form1` because when I asked perviously about passing data from one form to another, someone informed me that it was easier to do it directly through `Form1` instead using the `form1` object.

Comment: How are you creating your SearchReplace Form, is it from Form1?

Comment: By running `Form1 form1 = new Form1();` you are creating a new (invisible) instance of your form. This is not the same instance as your mian form that is being displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Based in your recent comment it's best to hide your current form (SearchReplace) before
calling Form1. And then close it once Form1 also is closed. Check my code below:

Let's say this is your `SearchReplace` form:

```
public partial class SearchReplace : Form
{
    Form1 form1;

    public SearchReplace()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close(); // When form1 is closed then close also SearchReplace form
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Form1.searchT = textBox1.Text; // assign textbox1 to searchT
        form1 = new Form1(); // instantiate first
        form1.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(form1_FormClosed); // When Form1 Close
        form1.searchText(); // Run searchText function
        form1.Show(); // Show Form1
        this.Hide(); // Make SearchReplace form invisible but still in memory
    }
}
```

And your `Form1` would be like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static string searchT; // Static searchT string as per your requirement

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


   public void searchText() // search function
   {

    if (searchT != null)
    {
        if (textBox1.TextLength > 0)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text.Contains(searchT))
            {
                textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.IndexOf(searchT);
                textBox1.SelectionLength = searchT.Length;
            }
        }
    }
  }    
}
```

Comment: Throws me an error saying cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead. How would i qualify it as a string?

Comment: @Mercifies use the code in this answer, it does not produce that error. Yours does because you declared `searchT` as static.

Comment: The problem with this code is that to open `SearchReplace` the user will already have data in a textbox1 in `form` so if I were to close it and open another it would erase the data

Comment: @Mercifies: Check my update. I'm using a static string searchT on this one. I've tested it and it works. I put values on textbox1 on Form1 though on design time to match with the input on Textbox1 in SearchReplace form.

Comment: I changed the code around to test if the `searchText()` works and it does when I open a new form a re-type the info and search for it. Problem is when I tried to change `Form1 form1 = new Form1();` to `Form1 form1;` it throws me that it is never assigned to and will always have null value. `form1.searchT = textBox1.Text;` throws error cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead. I have it as a public static string in `Form1` not sure why its giving me this problem

Comment: @Mercifies I forgot the `form1 = new Form1();` also `form1.searchT = textbox1.Text` to `Form1.searchT = textbox1.Text;`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're creating an entirely new `Form` on the button click. You should be able to accomplish what you want with just this:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1.searchT = textBox1.Text;
    searchText(); //Calls this instance's searchText() function
    this.Close();
}
```

You might want to make `searchT` non-static, otherwise its value will apply to all instances of `Form1`.

Comment: I have to create a new object of it because just typing in `searchText();` throws me an error saying it doesn't exist. I have to create the object to call upon it.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a reference to the textbox in form1 to the constructor of form searchreplace.
Then use this reference to select the given text.

Answer (score 0):

Depending how you create your `SearchReplace` Form you can assign `Form1` as the Owner by using the [`Show`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szcefbbd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w61zzfwe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Method that allows you to set the owning form, then instead of relying on setting a variable in Form1 just pass the parameter to your Function. Something like this should work for you.

**Form1**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void searchText(string searchT) // search function
    {

        if (searchT != null)
        {
            if (textBox1.TextLength > 0)
            {
                if (textBox1.Text.Contains(searchT))
                {
                    textBox1.Focus(); // put focus to the Textbox so we can see our selection
                    textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.IndexOf(searchT);
                    textBox1.SelectionLength = searchT.Length;

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SearchReplace sr = new SearchReplace(); // Creating your SearchReplace Form
        sr.Show(this);  // Pass the creating form in as the Owner
    }
}
```

**SearchReplace Form**

```
public partial class SearchReplace : Form
{
    public SearchReplace()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((Form1)this.Owner).searchText(textBox1.Text); //Cast the Owner to Form1 and access the Function 
                                                       //passing in your search Parameter
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code, except that you only declare which text will be selected, don't expect it to automatically highlight, I suggest you change the backgroundcolor or the selected text to highlight it.
try my example.

and I **SUGGEST** that you use `RichTextBox`

in your Form1 is suppose you declare a

```
public static string searchT;
```

then in your `Form1`
show the searchReplace form as a `Dialog`

```
        private void searchReplaceBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 frm = new Form2();
            if (frm.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                searchText();
            }
        }
```

then in your `SearchReplace Form`

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1.searchT = textBox1.Text;
            this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
        }
```

finally in your `searchtext Method`

```
        private void searchText()
        {

            if (searchT != null)
            {
                if (textBox1.TextLength > 0)
                {
                    int index = 0;
                    //this will loop through the entire richTextBox
                    while (index < textBox1.Text.LastIndexOf(searchT))
                    {
                        //this will select the text that matches the searchT
                        textBox1.Find(searchT, index, textBox1.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
                        //this will change the background color of each of the selected text
                        textBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
                        //this will continue searching to the end of the text
                        index = textBox1.Text.IndexOf(searchT, index) + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**NOTE:** you can't select multiple text in textbox, that's why changing the backcolor of each of the text that matches your `searchT` will be the best option.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this one by using a property and giving the value of that certain textbox.

In your form1:

```
public static string Text
{
   get { return textbox1.Text; }
}
```

And you can get it at your other form by

```
form1.Text;
```